# Error calling remote scalar-valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am making a call from a sql 2005 database to a sql 2000 scalar-valued function and recieve the following error message:

```
Remote table-valued function calls are not allowed.
```

here is my call:

```
select * from [server/instance].[db name].dbo.[function name](param1, param2)
```

not sure why it says table-valued function, but that's the error message it get.  Does anyone know of a way around this?

thanks in advance,
Billy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only table-valued functions can be used in the `FROM` clause.

If it's a scalar function, use this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    OPENQUERY(SERVER, 'SELECT [db name].dbo.[function name](param1, param2)')
```

Comment: with this i receive and error stating: Invalid column name '[server/instance]'.

Comment: @BillyLogan should be '[server\instance]' - use a backslash instead of a forward slash.